# How to Loop To Get Input Again - Java

Tags: java, loops

I'm creating a game of Twenty One and I'm stuck on how to implement the loops. What I want to do is introduce the game ("Welcome to 21!"), ask the player to roll the dice by typing y, and give them the values of their dice rolls. Then, I want to loop back and ask them to roll the dice a second time by asking them to type y. If they don't type 'y', I want a message to appear telling them they have to type y to play the game. Basically, they will continue being asked if they want to play until they press y.

This is my code thus far. The problem I'm having is if the user presses 'm' instead of 'y', it will tell them "enter y to play the game", but if the user presses y after that, it will keep telling them they have to press y (even though they already did this second time).

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.Random;

 public class TwentyOne {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to 21!");

    System.out.print("Roll the dice, y/n?: ");
    String roll1 = input.nextLine();

        while (true) {
            if(roll1.equals("Y") || roll1.equals("y")) {
                int die1 = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                int die2 = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                int sum1 = die1 + die2;

        System.out.println("Your dice rolled a sum of: " + sum1);
            break;
         } 
        else {
    System.out.println("Please press 'y' to roll the dice and play. ");
              String rollError = input.nextLine();
        }


} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have assign the second input to `rollError` `String rollError = input.nextLine();` and you not using it to check the new user input `if(roll1.equals("Y") || roll1.equals("y"))`. Change `String rollError = input.nextLine();` to `roll1 = input.nextLine();`

Answer (score 0):

This one here will infinitely prompt the user for new rolls (all triggered by pressing the "y", notice the equalsIgnoreCase() too) since that is your described need. But if you ever need a game which ends, don't forget to close (input.close()) the Scanner object to prevent leaks.

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to 21!");
    boolean isYPressed = false;
    String roll1 = "";

    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Roll the dice, y/n?: ");
        roll1 = input.nextLine();
        isYPressed = roll1.equalsIgnoreCase("y");

        while (!isYPressed) {
            System.out.println("Please press the Y key");
            roll1 = input.nextLine();
            isYPressed = roll1.equalsIgnoreCase("y");
        }

        int die1 = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        int die2 = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        int sum1 = die1 + die2;

        System.out.println("Your dice rolled a sum of: " + sum1);
    }
```